# Please help determine if section of wall is load bearing

Tags: bathroom, structural, load-bearing, closet

I have 2 closets in the bathroom that I want to combine into 1 large open space for make up counter and some built in storage/cabinets. Between the 2 closets is the wall and there is a post (2x4) that's going up to the A frame of the roof. Does this look like it's load bearing? The floor joists run parallel to those 2 closet openings. Below is another bedroom and a small powder room. Appreciate the insight.

[image]

Additional picture from the attic

[image]

Comment: This is one of the few cases of "is this load bearing" having a pretty clear answer from a picture. If you really want to continue with this project, you _can_ do so, **however**, you will need to consult a structural engineer and/or architect (who will likely have one on staff/contract) to redesign the load bearing part of the structure to allow you to _safely_ remove this wall.

Answer (score 4):

You do NOT want to remove that double 2x4 post. It is very clearly load bearing as per the blue arrow that I added. The red downward pointing arrow shows the obvious sloping roof section overhead that be being supported there. There may be more that is supported at that corner that is not apparent from the picture.

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/265799/7367)*</sup>

In my evaluation I would suggest that you do not want to remove any bit of the below pictured wall as it also appears to be a support for things above.

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/265799/7367)*</sup>